# Cant't edit or delete post in laravel project

Tags: laravel

Hello dear i have an problem when user need too delete or edit post , laravel show error " you can't edit post ... " i use a model and controller in laravel and user "auth" system id for access post for delete or edit now see my work :

**Index View**

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
@auth
    <h6 class="alert alert-dark">Dear Guest {{ Auth::user()->name }} for send a post <a class="btn btn-success" href="{{ route('ads.create') }}">Click</a> Here</h6>
@endauth

@guest
    <div class="alert alert-primary">for send a post you can <a class="btn btn-success" href="{{ route('register') }}">Register</a></div>
@endguest

@if(count($adses) > 0)
<div class="row">
    @foreach($adses as $ads)
        <div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
            <div class="card mb-4">
                <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="/storage/cover_images/{{$ads->cover_image}}" alt="Card image cap">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h6 class="card-title"><a href="/ads/{{ $ads->id }}">{{ $ads->title }}</a></h6>
                    @if(!Auth::guest())
                        @if(Auth::user()->id == $ads->user_id)
                    <div class="row">
                        {!!Form::open(['action' => ['AdsController@destroy', $ads->id], 'method' => 'POST',]) !!}
                            {{Form::hidden('_method', 'DELETE')}}
                            {{Form::submit('Delete', ['class' => 'btn btn-danger'])}}
                        {!!Form::close() !!}
                        <a href="/ads/{{ $ads->id }}/edit" class="btn btn-primary mr-4">Edit</a>
                    </div>
                        @endif
                    @endif
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    @endforeach
    {{ $adses->links() }}
@else
<p class="alert alert-warning" role="alert">any post !</p>
</div>
@endif




@endsection
```

*Ads Model*

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Ads extends Model
{
  protected $table = 'ads';
  public $primaryKey = 'id';
  public $timestamps = true;

public function user(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
}
```

**User model**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
use Notifiable;

/**
 * The attributes that are mass assignable.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $fillable = [
    'name', 'email', 'password',
];

/**
 * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $hidden = [
    'password', 'remember_token',
];

public function adses(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Ads');
}
}
```

**Ads Controller**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
use App\Ads;



class AdsController extends Controller
{

/**
 * Create a new controller instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth', ['except' => ['index', 'show']]);
}

/**
 * Display a listing of the resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function index()
{
    $adses = Ads::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(16);
    return view('ads.index')->with('adses', $adses);
}

/**
 * Show the form for creating a new resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function create()
{
    return view('ads.create');
}

/**
 * Store a newly created resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'title' => 'required',
        'body' => 'required',
        'adsType' => 'required',
        'cover_image' => 'image|nullable|max:1999',
    ]);
    // Handle File Upload
    if($request->hasFile('cover_image')){
        // Get filename with the extension
        $filenameWithExt = $request->file('cover_image')->getClientOriginalName();
        // Get just filename
        $filename = pathinfo($filenameWithExt, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
        // Get just ext
        $extension = $request->file('cover_image')->getClientOriginalExtension();
        // Filename to store
        $fileNameToStore= $filename.'_'.time().'.'.$extension;
        // Upload Image
        $path = $request->file('cover_image')->storeAs('public/cover_images', $fileNameToStore);
    } else {
        $fileNameToStore = 'noimage.jpg';
    }
    $ads = new Ads();
    $ads->title = $request->input('title');
    $ads->body = $request->input('body');
    $ads->adsType = $request->input('adsType');
    $ads->user_id = auth()->user()->id;
    $ads->cover_image = $fileNameToStore;
    $ads->save();
    return redirect('/home')->with('success', 'آگهی شما با موفقیت درج شد .');
}

/**
 * Display the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function show($id)
{
    $ads = Ads::find($id);
    return view('ads.show')->with('ads', $ads);
}

/**
 * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  \App\Ads  $ads
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function edit($id)
{
    $ads = Ads::find($id);
    if(auth()->user()->id !== $ads->user_id){
        return redirect('/')->with('error', 'you cant edit other user's post');
    }
    return view('ads.edit')->with('ads', $ads);
}

/**
 * Update the specified resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \App\Ads  $ads
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'title' => 'required',
        'body' => 'required',
        'adsType' => 'required',
        'cover_image' => 'required',
    ]);

    // Handle File Upload
    if($request->hasFile('cover_image')){
        // Get filename with the extension
        $filenameWithExt = $request->file('cover_image')->getClientOriginalName();
        // Get just filename
        $filename = pathinfo($filenameWithExt, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
        // Get just ext
        $extension = $request->file('cover_image')->getClientOriginalExtension();
        // Filename to store
        $fileNameToStore= $filename.'_'.time().'.'.$extension;
        // Upload Image
        $path = $request->file('cover_image')->storeAs('public/cover_images', $fileNameToStore);
    }

    $ads = Ads::find($id);
    $ads->title = $request->input('title');
    $ads->body = $request->input('body');
    $ads->adsType = $request->input('adsType');
    if($request->hasFile('cover_image')){
        $ads->cover_image = $fileNameToStore;}
    $ads->save();
    return redirect('/')->with('success', 'your post is update');
}

 /**
  * Remove the specified resource from storage.
  *
  * @param  int  $id
  * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
  */
public function destroy($id)
{
    $ads = Ads::find($id);

    if(auth()->user()->id !== $ads->user_id){
        return redirect('/')->with('error', 'you cant delete other user's post');
    }

    if($ads->cover_image != 'noimage.jpg'){
        // Delete Image
        Storage::delete('public/cover_images/'.$ads->cover_image);
    }

    $ads->delete();
    return redirect('/')->with('success', 'Post Removed');
}
}
```

**Routs**

```
Auth::routes();
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
Route::resource('/', 'AdsController');
Route::resource('ads', 'AdsController');
```

now , after send a post and login in system user cant delete or edit her post .

Thank you

Comment: can you show us the full error message?

Comment: Thus can you tell us if this `$ads = Ads::find($id);` actually returns something? Just run following after that `dd($ads)`

Comment: @utdev when user click delete or edit post , see this Error : you cant delete other user's post , i use this error in my controller and when i use the dd($ads) return me the array of post

Comment: Paste it again it does not show up :)

Comment: sorry edit the comment now

Comment: Oh well it goes into this branch `if(auth()->user()->id !== $ads->user_id){
        return redirect('/')->with('error', 'you cant edit other user's post');
    }` and returns your own error message

Comment: I dont know what the dependencies are regarding that branch you could for example commentt that condition and try it again just to be sure that that is the reason

Comment: i use many branch for test and I'm sure this is not a branch issue i'm upload this project in gitlab (Private Project) , I can give you access to the review , can you review this project in gitlab ? This project is very small

Comment: I could have a quick look but I can not invest much time today anymore I could have a more detail look tomorrow if you like to

Comment: ok dear thank you so much can you tell me a user name in gitlab for add you in my private project ? If it can be a short moment to look at it, it would be great , however thank you

Comment: I actually have to read through gitlab never tried it before give me a minute

Comment: ok I registered my account name is ut dev you could maybe search for 28development@gmail.com not sure what excatly the account name is

Comment: thank you for register , i added you in project and you can access all of the codes.

Comment: ok got it ill have a look

Comment: This condition makes no sense to me right now `if(auth()->user()->id !==$ads->user_id){` could you explain why you did that if you do not need that could you remove it and try it out again.

Comment: This item is intended to examine the user's id.
If both are identical, the user can edit or delete the post.
In the database of registered information, the conversation confirms this, however, the user can not delete or edit his post.
This should be the case.

Comment: Hmm ok I will have a more detailed look at it tomorrow if its ok, its possible to clone the project on gitlab correct?

Comment: you can use any git command like github , you can clone and fork

Answer (score 0):

```
auth()->user()->id !== $ads->user_id .
```

Уou have this line. And if user not login when he creating post, you are will be have user_id == null. Check in DB than user_id?

Comment: any user cant send a post , if user login in system , then can send a post i use his method in controller can you see ? , in database any post have an id of user and save in database correctly

Comment: maybe try this? change condition "!==" to "!="

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem

```
 if(auth()->user()->id !== $ads->user_id)
```

Since you're using !==, make sure your user_id is integer